# Insert Sub-headers in List View, SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with over 80 fields of data.  I would like to insert sub-headers in the list view so I can group the fields by topic, allowing users to get to what they need quickly.  Any assitance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the view (or create a new one) and use the Group By functionality in the view settings. This will create a 'subheader' for all grouped items. Of course it will be needed to have a 'topic' column to be able to group the items by it